# process time with null value

Tags: php

Stuck trying to figure out the best algorithm here.  I have this simple function where the input is seconds:

```
function strTime($s) {
  $d = intval($s/86400);
  $s -= $d*86400;

  $h = intval($s/3600);
  $s -= $h*3600;

  $m = intval($s/60);
  $s -= $m*60;

  if ($d) $str = $d . 'day ';
  if ($h) $str .= $h . 'hr ';
  if ($m) $str .= $m . 'min ';
  if ($s) $str .= $s . 'sec';

  return $str;
}
```

I like this because it will only show what is needed.  For example if the seconds are at 3600 the output of this function will be "1 hr".

My issue is that in some cases the seconds will be 0 (when they start using the product).  How can I show 0 secs in those cases but in other times like the example above I don't want it to say "1 hr 0 sec".  I'm struggling to think of a way to do this.

Comment: so you use cases would be
1.) if it is the only value ie. 0, then display 0 secs
2.) if there is a larger value then do not display 0 secs, ie. 1 hr and not 1 hr 0 secs
is that right?

Comment: It's better for you to define `$str` before using in concatenation, if you have no day you'll hit warning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check to see if the string is still empty after all four if statements have run. You also have an error where you append data to an uninitiated string if `$d` is 0; you should instead initialize $str explicitly and make all four `if` statements append.

```
$str = "";

if ($d) $str .= $d . 'day ';
if ($h) $str .= $h . 'hr ';
if ($m) $str .= $m . 'min ';
if ($s) $str .= $s . 'sec';

return $str ? $str : "0 sec";
```

That is, "if we have seconds, *or the string is still empty*, show the number of seconds".

You should be expanding on each `if` statements to allow for pluralization as well, and possibly ignoring only the leading/trailing zeros instead of *all* zeros.

What I mean is that these examples look weird:

> 2 day 5 min
>   5 day 1 sec
>   1 hr 5 sec

You probably *want* the zeros for the intermediate units:

> 2 day 0 hr 5 min
>   5 day 0 hr 0 min 1 sec
>   1 hr 0 min 5 sec

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be good for you:

```
if (empty($str) &&  $s == 0)
   $str = '0 secs';
else
   $str .= $s . 'sec';
```